# Display Drop Down Menu "dynamically"?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to display the drop down menu I have below based on users' role:

```
<nav id="topNav">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Applications</a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="app1.php">App1</a></li>
    <li><a href="app2.php">App2</a></li>
    <li class="last"><a href="app3.php">App3</a></li>
   </ul>
  <li><a href="#">Corporate</a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="corporate1.php">Corporate1</a></li>
    <li><a href="corporate2.php">Corporate2</a></li>
    <li class="last"><a href="corporate3.php">Corporate3</a></li>
   </ul>        
  </li>
  <li class="last"><a href="#">I.T.</a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="IT1.php">IT 1</a>
    <li class="last"><a href="IT2.php">IT 2</a></li>
   </ul>   
  </li>      
 </ul>
</nav>
```

In my database, I have a table with the fields ID, email and role.
My application will first check if the user should be authenticated, then check the user's role (Staff / Agent) to display different content of the drop down menu. An agent doesn't need to view all items.

Currently I'm using simple "If else" statement to do this.

```
<?php
If($checkrole == "Staff") {?>
   <nav>
      display staff items
   </nav>
<?php}?>
<?else {?>
   <nav>
      display agent items
   </nav>
<?php } ?>
```

Is there any javascript or php function that allow me to display those menu items more dynamically ? If I have more roles in future, let say 10 roles, my current method is not a good option which is a bit static or hard-coded. Can anyone give me some examples or helps ? Thanks

Comment: JavaScript would be the same as you do now in PHP. Maybe add another table in your database to define what each role should be able to see?

Comment: You could just create two different nav's.. just as you have your code now. In other words one nav for staff and one for agents

Answer (score 0):

Create a table in your database and give every menu item an unique id and add a table where you define your roles with their unique menu id's. Then in your PHP page create a multidimensional array like `1 => 'home', 2 => 'anotherPage'`. Get your data from the database and loop through them with a foreach.

Table 'roles' => field: 'role', field => 'permission' with values 'agent', '1|2|3'

In your PHP file:

- get data
- explode data(explode('|', array);
- multidimenional array => 1 => 'home' etc.
- Loop trough the exploded data

Good luck!